# How to get row with rows salesforce opportunity id from a dataset of Opportunity History(Left) and opportunity(Right)

Tags: einstein, saql, data-set

Below is the SAQL being tried by me.

```
q = load "RELAOpportunityDataset";
q = filter q by 'Opportunity.OpptyRecType.Name' == "RELA Opportunity";
q = foreach q generate q.'Opportunity.Id' as 
'Opportunity.Id',q.'Opportunity.StageName' as 'Opportunity.StageName';

result_A = load "RELAOpportunityDataset";
result_A = filter result_A by 'Opportunity.OpptyRecType.Name' == "RELA 
Opportunity";
result_A = group q by 'Opportunity.Id';
result_A = foreach result_A generate result_A.'Opportunity.Id' as 
'Opportunity.Id';
Cgr = cogroup result_A by 'Opportunity.Id' left , q by 'Opportunity.Id';
result_B = foreach Cgr generate result_A.'Opportunity.Id' as 
'Opportunity.Id',q.'Opportunity.StageName' as 'Opportunity.StageName' ;
```

I am receiving error as **Unknown IDTOKEN: Opportunity.StageName**

Answer (score 0):

You never generate a field with the name 'Opportunity.StageName'.

The last line, `result_B = foreach Cgr generate result_A.'Opportunity.Id' as 
'Opportunity.Id',q.'Opportunity.StageName' as 'Opportunity.StageName' ;`, cannot generate the field unless the set you're iterating (in this case, `cgr`) includes the field that you want.

You want to add the field to the sets before, or it's not going to be found by your last line.

Comment: Can you please help me on how to generate the required field.
PS. I am new to wave.

Comment: You have to adjust the fields in the lines that say `generate` so your field is properly output.

Comment: Example: `foreach result_A generate result_A.'Opportunity.Id' as 
'Opportunity.Id', 'Opportunity.StageName' as 'Opportunity.StageName' `